# What is jQuery's "$.fn" equivalent in Prototype Framework?

Tags: jquery, object, prototypejs

I want to rewrite a simple jQuery function so that it works in a prototype.js-application. But I'm not really familiar with prototype and I failed googling because `$.fn` in jQuery means prototype so I only get search results for jQuery examples :D

But I just would like to know what `$.fn` would be in the Prototype framework.

jQuery example:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(parameters){
    ...
};
```

Comment: $.prototype.myFunction ?????

Comment: What's in the body of your function? What I usually do to add abilities to elements is use `Element.addMethods({ signature: function(element){ /* do whatever to element here */ return element; });` Then you can just call `$('some_element').signature();` and it will work.